# Nameservers and migrating a VPS

Tags: domains, web-hosting, cpanel, vps, nameserver

I am primarily a front end developer who has been tasked with upgrading my companies VPS.

As far as I understand, this is just the process of obtaining a new VPS with WHM/CPanel and then migrating the existing accounts over to the new VPS, testing the sites out, then pointing the DNS to the new nameserver records.

That sounds pretty straightforward.

What I am having trouble understanding is how to set up the new nameservers on the new VPS.

How do I obtain/establish the new nameserver records for the new, blank VPS?

Comment: The new VPS provider will have given you an IP address for the instance, which you use to update the DNS A Record(s) at the domain name's Registrar. Does this better describe what you need to do? If yes, it might be smart to set up a subdomain `test.<domainname>.<tld>` first to be sure everything works, then drop the subdomain once tested & working.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a VPS hosting provider? If so they might be able to help you switch the DNS. Usually a website or company doesn't run their own DNS (unless they are huge eg. Google). They might have the hosting provider or the Domain registration company list the IP in their DNS servers. Unless you are asking specifically "How to Run a DNS server" Then you might want to look into the corresponding Linux software which is over my head as far as the skills even needed to setup the server and register it with ICANN or who ever.

Comment: The linux daemon required to setup is named I believe. Have configured this in the past and I am more than happy to rely on the domain registrar's nameservers!!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you purchase a vps, there's a dns section where you can add nameservers, ie, ns1 and/or ns2 if you have 2 ip addresses. DirectAdmin has it and cPanel does.

So in the vps admin area you add the ns1/ns2 dns nameservers and at the registrar, you add those nameservers.

For example, in vps admin, you add ns1.mysite.com and ns2.mysite.com. At the registrar you add the same nameservers in the dns section. The dns nameservers in the vps controls all sites hosted on the vps as well as your mail server.